# Is UDP full duplex or half duplex?

Tags: networking, udp

Can someone tell me if UDP is simplex/half duplex/full duplex?

I read conflicting answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325368/is-udp-in-java-or-otherwise-full-duplex-by-default) and [here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/udp-gt-simplex-half-duplex-or-full-duplex/td-p/3207211).

Would be great if someone can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP has no concept of duplex. You can send and receive UDP datagrams and the underlying transport mechanism may or may not have full duplex capability. Nothing about UDP limits you to half duplex.